# Sybase TSQL access to table or view

Tags: t-sql, sap-ase

When I select all data from table/view person from database city I'll do it like this:

```
select * from city..person
```

ASE then substitutes the * to all the columns and .. for .dbo. and the query will be this:

```
select name, age, sex from city.dbo.person
```

If I have another view person created by another user (lets call it boss), and I want to access that view I need to make a select like this:

```
select * from city.boss.person
```

**Is there a way to make the city..person to be city.boss.person instead of city.dbo.person?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The naming convention in Sybase to identify a table/view is `[[database.]owner.]table_or_view_name`, which means that the `database` and `owner` qualifiers are optional.

If you don't specify them, `database` is expanded to the current database and `owner` is expanded to the current user.

In your example, `city..person` expanded to `city.dbo.person`, because you're running under `dbo` user. The only way to have ASE expanding `city..person` to `city.boss.person`, is running the query under the `boss` user.